# Adding users to a group which aren't already member of it Indirect

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm having trouble with my pscode.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

## Config

```
$counter = 0
$allready_members = 0
$allready_members_file = "c:\temp\allready_members.txt"
$new_members = 0
$new_members_file = "c:\temp\new_members.txt"
$groupname = "EU-GPO-CTXPVS.MinimumIdleSessionTime.Users"
$fnc_accounts = @()
$allready_member_accounts = @()
```

## Begin

```
Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "- querying ActiveDirectory for FNC-accounts..."
Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------"

Clear-Content $new_members_file
Clear-Content $allready_members_file

$fnc_accounts = Get-ADUser -Properties MemberOf, DisplayName, samAccountName, PasswordExpired -Filter  {(Enabled -eq "True") -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq "True")} | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -like '*OU=FNC*') } | select Displayname, samAccountName, PasswordExpired 

$allready_member_accounts = Get-ADGroupMember $groupname -Recursive | select samAccountName
```

## Main

```
foreach($fncaccount in $fnc_accounts) {

    if (($allready_member_accounts -notcontains $fncaccount.samAccountName)){
        #Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Members $fncaccount.sAMAccountName
        Write-Host "+ User "$fncaccount.SamAccountName" added to "$groupname
        #Add-Content -Path $new_members_file $fncaccount.samAccountName
        $new_members++
    } else {    
        Write-Host "- User "$fncaccount.SamAccountName" is already a member of "$groupname
        #Add-Content -Path $allready_members_file $fncaccount.samAccountName
        $allready_members++
    }

$counter++

}
```

## End

```
Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------" 
Write-host "- # FNC count          : "$fnc_accounts.Count
Write-Host "- # allready count     : "$allready_member_accounts.Count
Write-host "- # allready counter   : "$allready_members
Write-host "- # new members counter: "$new_members
Write-host "- # items processed    : "$counter
Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
```

My ps script doesn't seem to find the matches in my arrays. Any ideas ? I've used the counters to see if my check in foreach is correct.

Comment: Can you give a description of the goal of this script? What will it be accomplishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using the Compare-Object CmdLet

```
$new_members_array = Compare-Object (Get-Content $path_fncaccounts_file) (Get-Content $path_already_members_file) | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}
```

eventually my problem is solved!